# Dust.js if Statement

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I want to do a simple if statement in Dust. If the product's fahig value is "true", I expect it to output "Yes". Else I want it to output "No".

My Dust setup is working fine. When I hard code the "true" or "false" value it works. But when I start messing with the if statement in my template, it doesn't work. So I'm assuming I have a syntax error in my if statement.

Template

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      {#matrix}
        <td>
          {@eq key=fahig value="True"}
            <span>Yes</span>
          {:else}
            <span>No</span>
          {/eq}
        </td>
      {/matrix}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

main.js

```
var data = {
  matrix: [{
    name: 'PM 1122',
    fahig: 'True'
  }, {
    name: 'MA-1410 B Mixer Preamp',
    fahig: 'False'
  }]
}

dust.render("matrix", data, function(err, out) {
    $('#matrix').append(out);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="matrix"></div>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is your code crashing or is the wrong result shown? What is the result you expect and what is the result you get? Can you elaborate a little more on the issue please?

Comment: If the products fahig value is "true", I expect it to output "True". Else I want it to output false. The problem is there's an error, so my page is not rendering.

Comment: what error? Can you please edit your question and add the important information from your comment as well as what the exact error message is. This may or may not be an issue related to the code you are showing us but we don't know that without all of the relevant information.

Comment: I updated the question with more info plus more code.

Comment: Are you trying to insert `td` elements directly into the `div`? That won't work as it is invalid HTML and the resulting HTML depends on the browser. In Chrome you end up with `<div id="matrix><span>No/yes</span></div>` for example instead. Where is the `<table><tr></tr></table>` ? If dust does any type of HTML validation before rendering it might refuse to render invalid HTML,..not sure as I never worked with dust myself.

Comment: I've updated the question again, adding the table. This is not a html issue. The issue is related to the Dust if statement. I've no idea how to implement an if statement in Dust and I'm trying to find out how.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your dust or the data. I pasted the dust into one panel and the JSON object part of the data into the other panel and got this output using the "dust test page": http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/test/test.html

```
<table><tbody><tr><td><span>Yes</span></td><td><span>No</span></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Be sure you have a recent enough version of dustjs-helpers to have eq helper.